# NoInteractionsWanted exception

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I'm writing test for my Service written in pure Java that will later migrate to Spring boot. This class just reads several scenarios from json and does infinite loop handling each scenario every time with interface *ScenarioHandler*:

```java
@Override
public void execute(ScenarioHandler handler) {
    execute(handler, () -> false);
}

public void execute(ScenarioHandler handler, TerminatorListener terminator) {
    List<Scenario> scenarioList = provider.readScenarios();
    validateScenarios(scenarioList);
    listen(scenarioList, handler, terminator);
}

private void listen(List<Scenario> scenarioList, ScenarioHandler handler, TerminatorListener terminator) {
    int currentIndex = 0;
    while (!terminator.shouldTerminate()) {
        Scenario scenario = scenarioList.get(currentIndex);
        handler.onScenarioReceived(scenario);
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % scenarioList.size();
        sleep();
    }
}
```

Here I've done method overloading to be able perform the testing.
I get a org.Mockito.exception.verifications.NoInteractionWanted exception, with this stack trace:

```
No interactions wanted here:
-> at executor.service.service.ScenarioSourceListenerTest.tearDown(ScenarioSourceListenerTest.java:65)
But found this interaction on mock 'scenarioProvider':
-> at executor.service.service.impl.ScenarioSourceListenerImpl.execute(ScenarioSourceListenerImpl.java:30)
Actually, above is the only interaction with this mock.
```

My test is provided here:

```java
private ScenarioProvider provider;

private ScenarioHandler handler;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    provider = mock(ScenarioProvider.class);
    handler = mock(ScenarioHandler.class);
    listener = new ScenarioSourceListenerImpl(provider);
}

@Test
public void testExecute_numberOfTimes() {
    int maxIterations = 5;
    TerminatorListener terminator = new TestTerminator(maxIterations);

    given(provider.readScenarios()).willReturn(prepareScenarioList());

    listener.execute(handler, terminator);

    verify(handler, times(maxIterations)).onScenarioReceived(any(Scenario.class));
}

@AfterEach
void tearDown() {
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(provider);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(handler);
}

private class TestTerminator implements TerminatorListener {
    private int maxIterations;
    private int currentIteration = 0;

    public TestTerminator(int maxIterations) {
        this.maxIterations = maxIterations;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldTerminate() {
        currentIteration++;
        return currentIteration > maxIterations;
    }
}
```

Where possibly can be another interaction with my provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Test
public void testExecute_numberOfTimes() {
    int maxIterations = 5;
    TerminatorListener terminator = new TestTerminator(maxIterations);

    given(provider.readScenarios()).willReturn(prepareScenarioList());

    listener.execute(handler, terminator);

    verify(handler, times(maxIterations)).onScenarioReceived(any(Scenario.class));
}

@AfterEach
void tearDown() {
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(provider);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(handler);
}
```

You are never calling `verify` on your provider. Therefore, there are still unverified interactions and `verifyNoMoreInteractions` will trip.

You must verify *all* interactions of your provider:

```
given(provider.readScenarios()).willReturn(prepareScenarioList());

listener.execute(handler, terminator);

verify(handler, times(maxIterations)).onScenarioReceived(any(Scenario.class));
verify(provider).readScenarios();
```